# Xamarin Visual Studio 2015- Todos os componentes da toolbox estão desabilitados

Tags: xamarin.android

Estou executando o lab01 da #MaratonaXamarin e depois de fazer todos os procedimentos para rodar o Android a tela do emulador aparece , porém preciso incluir o botão "hello world" mas a tollbox está com todos os componentes desabilitados.
Sabem como faço para habilitar os controles da toolbox ?

Obrigado

Answer (score 0):

Alison, boa noite.

Provavelmente esta faltando alguma API ou SDK

Veja qual o emulador que teu projeto esta abrindo, por exemplo se ele mostra KitKat Android 4.4 ao lado API 19

dai no Android SDK Manager selecione na pasta Tools a maior revisão da api que tu precisa.
Exemplo revisão 19.1 para API 19 
a API e na pasta Android X.x(API XX) dai tu seleciona Android 4.4.2(API 19)

tente isto,veja se ajuda.

t+

Edson

Comment: Obrigado Edson pela sugestão.     O Emulador no vs é o Android 4.4 -API 19.  Verifiquei no meu SDK e já estava com todas as revisões da API 19 instaladas e também na pasta tools a revisão 19.1 também já estava instalada. Alguma outra sugestão ?

Comment: tente instalar o http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk8-downloads-2133151.html conforme a sua versão do windows.